# ¿Por que no logro realizar una consulta desde mi app?

Tags: android-studio

Trato de realizar una consulta desde mi app a una base de datos que hice en workbench e lo importe usando xampp y me arroja estos mensajes al momento de hacer la consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy usando esta librería para la conexión: mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin

este es el codigo que uso:

```
public Connection conexionDB() {
    Connection cnn = null;
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy politica = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(politica);

        Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();

        cnn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.102:3306;databaseName=innovet;user=adia;password=adia;");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return cnn;

}

public void consulta() {
    try {
        Statement stm = (Statement) conexionDB().createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM orden WHERE Num_orden" + editTextNumOr.getText().toString() + "'");

        if (rs.next()) {
            editTextCli.setText(rs.getString(3));
            editTextPro.setText(rs.getString(4));

        }

        editTextNumOr.setText("");

        } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio,agrega el còdigo que estas tratando, por favor revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: No te conecta a la db. de ahi en mas, todo error que salga es irrelevante.. e igual, tu sql no esta bien formado...

Comment: Hola, gracias, si ya agregue el código.

Answer (score -1):

Marca error por el puerto definido, si estas realizando una conexión usando mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin  , te sugiero realices la conexión de la siguiente forma:

```
public Connection conexionDB() {
    Connection cnn = null;
    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy politica = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(politica);

       // Class.forName("org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver").newInstance();
          Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

       // cnn = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.102:3306;databaseName=innovet;user=adia;password=adia;");

          cnn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://192.168.8.102:3306/innovet","adia","adia");


    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    return cnn;

}
```